# What is it called "are + past tense"

Tags: grammar, tenses

I'm reviewing English grammar from the beginning, so I have a very basic question. I want to know what it is called when we use "are + past format" in a sentence. In example:

- They are normally printed in a company.
- Mongo trees, which are densely covered with glossy leaves, grow rapidly.

I know this question might seems really stupid to you, but its a real question and it makes some confusion in my mind. [In this link](https://www.easypacelearning.com/design/images/tenses.jpg) we can see almost all verb tenses we have and I didn't find this format in this cheat sheet.

This question is not a duplicate of any other question, it is just my personal confusion regarding passive tenses in a special case.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks for the clarification. But in the present perfect, we have two fromats. First is present perfect which consist of *BE* + have been, and we have present perfect continuous which consists of *BE* + have been + present participle. My examples are not matching with these 2 formats, so what are they ?

Comment: Sorry, stupid mistake on my part: *BE* + past participle is **passive**, not perfect.

Comment: @StoneyB Please send your comment as an answer and I will mark it as accepted. So many thanks.

Comment: The two examples are not the same. Densely covered is not passive.  It compares to "The subject is closed."  The door is red, and it is red because it is painted red.  We are not asking painted red by whom, the telltale sign of the passive.  Some wooden doors are unfinished, some are painted red.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Covered by what? sumelic is in the right here. This is most certainly passive. The example you gave used "closed" as an adjective (not open), not as a passive verb, unlike the sentences in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @StoneyB mentioned in the comments, it's called a **passive** format.